# Compare values from multiple columns

Tags: excel, comparison, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to compare values from multiple columns and then highlight the row if it matches my criteria using conditional formatting. For example: in the table below, there are four columns, and I want to compare the values within the the 3 columns: A-C. If they all match, then I want to highlight the entire row. When I use conditional formatting, I'm only able to compare two of the three. I don't know the syntax to compare more than columns.

```
        A         B        C
Name  Has Dog   Has Cat  Has Bird
  A     Y         Y        Y
  B     Y         N        Y
  C     Y         Y        N
  D     N         N        Y
  E     Y         Y        N
```

Comment: How about =AND($A$1=$B$1,$B$1=$C$1) ... If they are all equal, evaluates to TRUE.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=AND($B1=$C1,$B1=$D1)
```

for Format values where this formula is true: and Applies to all the columns you have available.

Comment: Works well. Just apply to one column, then use Format Painter to apply to the other 2 columns.

Comment: I assumed that meant the entire row of data, not the entire spreadsheet row.